# Traffic shaping: tc filter catch all filter

Tags: qos, traffic-shaping, filter, tc

How Can I configure a **"catch all"** filter with `tc filter`?

I tested with the following code but it gave me the error: `"Unknown filter "1:100", hence option "protocol" is unparsable"`:

```
tc filter add dev $IF_LAN parent 1:100 protocol ip prio 7 flowid 1:190
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give something like this a try for a catch-all

```
tc filter add dev $IF_LAN parent 1: protocol ip prio 7 u32 match ip dst 0.0.0.0/0 flowid 1:190
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is rather old, but just in case someone comes across a similar problem.

Parameter `all` can be used for protocol instead of `ip` to also filter for other traffic like arp.

```
tc filter add dev $IF_LAN parent 1: protocol all prio 7 u32 match u32 0 0 flowid 1:190
```

Also `match u32 0 0` is a shorter expression to filter all traffic.