# Network shaping using `tc netem` doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, tc

I'm trying to simply delay traffic targeted for certain IP address on Ubuntu 16.06 box with no luck.
There are plenty of resources as [this](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/389290/using-tc-to-delay-packets-to-only-a-single-ip-address) [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/#intro) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/537328/tc-netem-and-iptables-delay-traffic-only-from-specified-ip-and-port) that I studied.
I ended up with these two sets of commands, neither of those work:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay 100ms
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.19.0.2/32 flowid 1:1
```

-- or --

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio priomap 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay 100ms
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.19.0.2/32 flowid 1:1
```

After executing them, all traffic is blocked - i.e. nothings comes out, host unreachable:

```
$ ping pingserver2
PING pingserver2 (172.19.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 14d25a894559 (172.19.0.3) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 14d25a894559 (172.19.0.3) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

$ ping pingserver
PING pingserver (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 14d25a894559 (172.19.0.3) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 14d25a894559 (172.19.0.3) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

It even does it right after I execute just the very first line.

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong with the approach I'm taking?

Comment: @anx `handle 10:` sets id for the qdisc being added

Answer (score 8):

I finally figured it out. After careful studying of [this](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.classful.html) and [this](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.filters.html) chapters I have much better understanding of how it is supposed to work and how `tc` processes packets.

So basically, what I need to do, is to build this kind of tree:

```
          1:   root qdisc
         / | \ 
       /   |   \
       /   |   \
     1:1  1:2  1:3    classes
      |    |    |
     10:  20:  30:    qdiscs    qdiscs
    netem sfq  ---
band  0    1    2
```

Which means, that apart from adding `netem` qdisc I needed to add `sfq` to the second band and add a filter for "catch-all" case. Here are all the commands I'm using:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.19.0.2 match ip dport 6363 0xffff flowid 1:1
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol all parent 1: prio 2 u32 match ip dst 0.0.0.0/0 flowid 1:2
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol all parent 1: prio 2 u32 match ip protocol 1 0xff flowid 1:2
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay 10ms
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 20: sfq
```

Here are explanations for every line above:

1. Add `prio` queueing discipline to the root with handle (id) `1:0` (0 is not mandatory) on interface `eth0`. `prio` qdisc has three classes by default - 1:1 1:2 and 1:3. These classes will be assigned filters on the next three lines (order matters!). It is important to understand how outgoing packets are processed - they enter tree from the root and **exit it from the root as well** (not falling off the leaves!).
2. Add filter for the traffic we want to slow down (it's the traffic going to `172.19.0.2` on port `6363` in my case). Filter attaches to the root node (`parent 1:`) - it means that all outgoing packets will be checked by this filter. Filter checks for ip and port (`ip dst ... ip dport ...`) and redirects to class `1:1` (`flowid 1:1`).
3. In similar fashion to the above, this is how "catch-all" filter is set (thanks this [post](https://serverfault.com/a/320618/464281)), redirects to class `1:2`.
4. Similarly, this filter is a "catch-all" for ICMP packets (ping packets), also redirects to `1:2`.
5. Attach `qdisc` to class `1:1`, give it a handle of `10:0` and let it be `netem` qdisc with delay 10ms.
6. Attach `sfq` qdisc to class `1:2` - this qdisc will handle all other packets that matched "catch-all" filter in a "stochastic fairness" fashion.

I highly recommend reading those chapters I gave links to as they clarify a lot of things and allow you to stop desperately googling for a solution and start designing network shaping on your own.

Also, I found these commands extremely useful for debugging/examining:

```
tc -s qdisc ls dev eth0
tc -s filter ls dev eth0
```

Comment: I get 404 on both links to chapters you refer to.

Comment: Thanks it works well and cleaner than the [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/964387/382373) I was previously using

Comment: Another reference that helps understand where the prio qdisc bands actually come from:  https://linux.die.net/man/8/tc-prio

Comment: Maybe someone reading this who uses etcd can comment on this issue https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/11469.  I don't know if the etcd docs are in error, but I can't see my way to saying they are correct, either.